# Why on clicking Ok the web form resets

Tags: javascript, asp.net, href

I have written the following script to pop up a message using `href` but on clicking `OK` of the pop up the form is getting reset why this is happening

What I wrote is as follows

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none;" onclick="return confirm('A student need for Accommodated, Modified, or Alternate assessment is determined by the student ARD committee working in collabration with the LPAC and must be documneted in the student IEP ');">
                                ?</a>
```

Before OK click

[image]

After clicking ok

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's odd that you're using `confirm()` for an informational pop-up.  There's no difference between OK and Cancel, so you can just use `alert()`, you also need to return false so it does not actually follow the link:

```
<a href="" onclick="confirm('Whatever'); return false;">?</a>
```

The original version you posted was linking to the current page (and reloading the page with a now empty form.)

You could also use a span:

```
<span onclick="confirm('Whatever');">?</span>
```

Comment: but alert doesn't provide yes/no options, which I think the OP was hoping to make use of.  Perhaps can confirm/discomfirm the intended behvaior.

Comment: @thescientist By my reading the OP's question and looking at the example, I do not think he was making use of OK/Cancel.

Comment: Yeah if i would like to have Ok and Cancel how can i then

Comment: @Dorababu you can still use `confirm()` instead of alert, but in this example what is the difference between clicking OK vs Cancel?  If you return the value of confirm, it will follow the link...  You can make the `href="#"` so the page doesn't reload...

Comment: @Fosco: first line of the post...  I have written the following script to pop up a message using href but on clicking _OK_ of the pop up.    @Dorababu: have you tried changing it to span or adding return false like has been suggested?

Comment: Hi fosco if i use '#` and after clicking ok of pop up and if i again try to refresh the page i am unable to clear all why?

Comment: @Dorababu You haven't explained... What is the difference between clicking OK versus Cancel on an *informational pop-up*??  @thescientist You know what people ask for isn't always what they want.  You're not thinking critically, look at the example and tell me what use OK and Cancel are in this case?  Awesome, I love down-votes on my accepted and correct answers.

Comment: @Dorababu you can remove the # as long as you are returning false in the click handler.

Comment: Fosco No difference that's just an information displaying to user

Comment: @Dorababu If there is no difference, then you should not have 2 buttons to click... `alert()` is what you should be using.  `confirm()` is for "Yes/No" style prompts such as "Are you sure you want to delete this?"

Comment: Fosco Ok but is it possible to run it with confirm as per my requirement

Comment: @Dorababu yes... `href="" onClick="confirm('Message'); return false;"`  or replace your whole `A` element with `<span onClick="confirm('Message');">?</span>`

Comment: Answer edited to match this final decision, but please consider avoiding confirm when there is nothing to actually confirm.

Answer (score 1):

that's because clicking OK in a confirm box will return true, which will cause the anchor to 
'continue' with it's default behavior, which in this case (without a defined href) will reload the current page.  Consider using a different tag, like < span >

edit: or as noted below, try adding

```
return false;
```

after the function call within the tag.

Comment: Can i have a brief description please how to use Span

Comment: span is just another HTML tag, which is also inline, like < a >.  just replace _a_ with _span_